# Separate CSS for nested elements

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following -

```
<div>
  <span>First</span>
  <span>Second</span>
  <span>Third</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use CSS to modify the style of each  separately, without having to apply a unique class in each case?

For example, something like `div span { color: blue; }` but then apply a different colour to the subsequent span and so on?

(...and yes, I have tried many Google searches first!)

Comment: `(...and yes, I have tried many Google searches first!)` `If it==true?"":"why people find duplicates?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `nth-of-type` or `nth-child`:

```
 span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color:blue;
 }
 span:nth-of-type(2) {
   color:red;
 }

 span:nth-of-type(3) {
    color:green;
 }
```

[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myvxdx) is the code example